# How do these column vectors [1,-3, 0], [-2 9 0], [0, 0, 0], and [0, -3, 5] not form a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given a question asking if the set of those 4 questions form a basis. The answer is that they do not.

I ignore the third vector which represents the origin, and because there is a 0 in the first row of the fourth vector, it must be linearly independent from the first 2 vectors.

Regarding the first 2 vectors, how can they be linearly dependent? Those two are not multiples of each other.

Comment: @gimusi all of your answers are good. You can all be co-first answer.

Comment: Almost all, some are very bad! Anyway you don't have neceaarly to choose mine, you have to choose which is the best for you, if you consider the problem soved. Bye!

Answer (score 4):

$0[1,-3,0]+0[-2,9,0]+1[0,0,0]+0[0,-3,5]=[0,0,0]$ but the coefficients are not all zeros.

Comment: Ok, so is it true that [0 0 0] is never linearly independent from anything?

Comment: Yes, right, the same trick goes for others.

Comment: Also, those four should still form a basis, correct?

Comment: Are you saying spanning?

Comment: Those four in the question, [1 -3 0]...

Comment: No, I mean basis. The question says: "Let W1 be the set of those four vectors. Is W1 a basis?"

Comment: Then of course not, as my reasoning has already said, they are not even linearly independent, basis needs at least linearly independence.

Comment: I don't see how these four vectors do not form a basis. They have 3 linearly independent equations. That should be enough

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention, it is in $R^3$, hence we only need 3 linearly independent equations

Comment: Because adding another zero column just messed all things up, basis needs linearly independence.

Comment: Wait so even if we have enough # of linearly independent vectors = dim(V), adding one additional dependent vector automatically disqualifies the set as a basis?

Comment: Yes, you got it right.

Comment: Ah great thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To be a basis for a space of dimension n a set of vector need to fullfil the following condition

- the vectors in the set are **exactly n**
- the vectors are **linearly independent**

In this case you have 4 vectors with n=3 and thus the set can't be a basis, moreover the vector $(0,0,0)$ is a trivial multiple of every vector thus it cant belong to any basis.

Excluding the zero vector you obtain a basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Comment: I think the definition is "they span and are linearly independent"

Comment: @gimusi In our case $n!$ would equal $6$. SCNR

Comment: Sorry, I don’t catch your point.

Comment: “... they must be at least n!”  Now, $3!=6$.

Comment: ah ok :) no it is not a factorial...and the need to be n exactly!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is precisely excluding the zero vector. Without it, you have a basis; with it - you don't.

Recall that the basis must be linearly independent. A zero vector makes it linearly dependent. Generally, if you have vectors $\mathbb{0},v_2,v_3,\ldots,v_n$, those are never linearly independent because $1\cdot \mathbb{0}+0\cdot v_2+0\cdot v_3+\cdots+0\cdot v_n=0$ but $1\ne 0$.